# Obtener las ganancias de dos tablas distintas (VENTAS y COMPRAS) usando inner join

Tags: mysql, join, inner

Tengo un inconveniente al momento de obtener las ganancias de dos tablas (VENTAS y COMPRAS) agrupadas por mes, al momento de obtener el resultado usando inner join en las ganancias no me sale el resultado que debería obtener por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obtengo correctamente los resultados de las ventas y compras, ahora, tengo que obtener en una nueva columna las ganancias de esos resultados, siempre agrupados por mes. Este seria el código que uso que según mi entendimiento estoy usando mal inner join ya que me cambia los datos de la columna de las compras y la ganancia no es el resultado: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTE seria el resultado que me tira:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito en resumidas palabras es que obtener el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

COMPARTO EL CÓDIGO FUENTE:

```sql
select
    fecha,
    ventas,
    compras
FROM
    (
    select
        MONTHNAME(v.fecha_venta) as fecha,
        SUM(v.total_venta) as VENTAS
    FROM
        ventas v
    WHERE
        YEAR(v.fecha_venta)= YEAR(NOW())
    GROUP BY
        MONTH(v.fecha_venta)DESC ) T1
LEFT JOIN
    (
    select
        MONTHNAME(c.fecha_compra) as fecha_compra,
        SUM(c.total_compra) as COMPRAS
    FROM
        compras c
    GROUP BY
        MONTH(c.fecha_compra)DESC) T2
    ON
    T1.fecha = T2.fecha_compra
```

Comment: Pon la consulta dónde obtienes los datos de las compras y ventas correctamente, es decir la consulta que te da los datos de la primera imagen que pones

Comment: select   
fecha,
ventas, 
compras
FROM
(select MONTHNAME(v.fecha_venta) as fecha, SUM(v.total_venta) as VENTAS FROM ventas v WHERE YEAR(v.fecha_venta)= YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY MONTH(v.fecha_venta)DESC ) T1 
LEFT JOIN
(select MONTHNAME(c.fecha_compra ) as fecha_compra, SUM(c.total_compra) as COMPRAS FROM compras c
GROUP BY MONTH(c.fecha_compra)DESC) T2
ON T1.fecha =T2.fecha_compra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Tbl.*, Tbl.ventas - Tbl.compras as ganancia
from
(
select fecha, ventas, compras 
FROM (select MONTHNAME(v.fecha_venta) as fecha, SUM(v.total_venta) as VENTAS 
      FROM ventas v 
      WHERE YEAR(v.fecha_venta)= YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY MONTH(v.fecha_venta)DESC ) T1 
LEFT JOIN (select MONTHNAME(c.fecha_compra ) as fecha_compra, SUM(c.total_compra) as COMPRAS 
           FROM compras c 
           GROUP BY MONTH(c.fecha_compra)DESC) T2 ON T1.fecha =T2.fecha_compra
) Tbl;
```

Sobre tu consulta original aplicas una consulta general, y **restas los campos ventas y compras** obteniendo las ganancias deseadas.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias! me funcióno ese codigo!